# Show that $\text{ker}(\alpha) \subseteq \text{ker}(\beta\alpha)$. If $\beta$ is one-to-one, show that $\text{ker}(\beta\alpha) =\text{ker}(\alpha) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism

> Let $\alpha : R \rightarrow  S$ and $\beta : S \rightarrow  T$ be ring homomorphisms.  Show that $\text{ker}(\alpha) \subseteq \text{ker}(\beta\alpha)$. If $\beta$ is one-to-one, show that $\text{ker}(\beta\alpha) =\text{ker}(\alpha) $

What I have done: Let $r\in \text{ker}(\alpha)$, then $\alpha(r)=0$. But $0\in \text{ker}(\beta) $. Thus $r\in \text{ker}(\beta\alpha)$, and hence $\text{ker}(\alpha) \subseteq \text{ker}(\beta\alpha)$. Also, if $\beta$ is one-to-one, we know that $\text{ker}(\beta) =\{0\}$, and hence $\text{ker}(\beta\alpha) =\text{ker}(\alpha) $, as desired.

This problem is easy to understand, but it was hard for me to write the proof. Is what I did okay? More than anything I have doubts in the first part, I think a little more clarity is needed. Can you help me please?

Comment: Looks OK until "and hence $\operatorname{ker}(\beta \alpha) = \operatorname{ker}(\alpha)$, as desired." Maybe add some more detail to make it clear why this follows from $\operatorname{ker}(\beta) = \{0\}$. Anyone can write "and hence [desired conclusion]" even if they don't really know why. :-D

Comment: For the first part it seems clear enough from what you wrote, but you could add the additional statement "so $\beta(\alpha(r)) = 0$" after "But $0 \in \operatorname{ker}(\beta)$".

Comment: @Bungo Yes! I needed that little detail. Although I understood, I did not see very clearly how they related

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of $\ker(\alpha)\subseteq\ker(\beta\alpha)$ is perfect.

As for the latter part, it would be better if you can write more details, e.g., since $\ker(\beta)=\{0\}$, for every $x\in\ker(\beta\alpha)$, we have $\alpha(x)=0$ whence $x\in\ker(\alpha)$. This gives the converse inclusion.